# Image resizing to fit on PDF page using Saxon HE Apache FOP XSL-FO XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, saxon, apache-fop

We are transforming XML to PDF using Saxon HE/ Apache FOP (XSLT 2.0). I would like to resize some of the images down to fit on the page. I understand to use the content-height and content-width "scale-down-to-fit" or "scale-to-fit" attributes but the height and width of the image is not available in the XML.
**I need a way to access the image file dimensions in the XSLT.**

Here is how a graphic might be depicted in the XML:

```
<graphic boardno="abcd.jpg" unitmeasure="in" inschlvl="0" delchlvl="0 />
```

Previously they were using xalan extensions (for v1.0 XSLT, we are upgrading to v.2)

```
xmlns:ii="xalan://ImageInfo" and xmlns:file="xalan://FileUtils"
```

and then in the XSL-FO:

```
<xsl:variable name="curGraphicUri">
    <xsl:value-of select="unparsed-entity-uri(@boardno)" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="imgProp">
    <xsl:value-of select="ii:setInputFile(string($curGraphicUri),72)" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="curFunctionStatus">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before($imgProp,';'),'status:')" />
</xsl:variable>
```

So (I'm thinking) if I knew the equivalent functions in FOP, or another available extension, I should be able to figure out the rest. I have searched these forums and I haven't found a similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `scale-down-to-fit` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#content-height), you don't need to know the original size of the graphic because the XSL-FO formatter will know that anyway.  If the full-size graphic will fit in the available space, then it will be rendered at 100% scale, otherwise the graphic will be reduced until it does fit within the available height/width.

If you were using a formatter that also supports `allowed-height-scale` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#allowed-height-scale) and `allowed-width-scale`, then you could also control the scale factors that are used when the image is scaled down to fit.  This can be useful, for example, to avoid Moiré patterns (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) or to keep a consistent scale (or set of scales) between related graphics (e.g., a selection of screenshots of the menus of an application).

Comment: Thank you, `scale-down-to-fit` has much better results but I had to add `width="100%"`

Comment: You could instead use `max-width` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#max-width), since it might better indicate your intention, but by using `scale-down-to-fit`, you've already stopped the formatter from scaling up small graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Section 3.1 of the EXPath Binary module gives you an example of how to do exactly this:

http://expath.org/spec/binary

Saxon (PE and higher) implements this library. (For Saxon-HE, however, you're out of luck).

Comment: Thank you. Would I replace the @href `<xsl:variable name="binary" select="file:read-binary(@href)" as="xs:base64Binary"/>` with the  `$curGraphicUri` variable from above and leave everything else the same as in the example?

Comment: Possibly. There may be issues about whether relative URIs are resolved relative to the source document or the stylesheet. And I can't vouch for the correctness or completeness of the example in the EXPath spec (it's conceivable it's simplified, or only handles particular cases).

Comment: Also, I'm confused by the use of `unparsed-entity-uri()` in your code. The value of `@boardNo` looks to me like a URI, not an entity name. Perhaps it is just an entity name that happens to look like a URI.

Comment: The entity references have a .jpg extension `<!ENTITY abcd.jpg ...`